# Is there a way to package up just the code that a visual studio solution references.

Tags: visual-studio, code-cleanup

I'm trying to tidy up a project that is a complete mess, there are several .sln files which each reference between 4 and 15 projects all in the same directory.

Some of the projects have the same or very similar names and are in differently nested directories.

Is there a sensible way to extract all the files that are referenced by a particular solution and it's project so I can put it into source control without all the extra stuff?

I assume it's possible to traverse the .sln file read in the project files listed in it and grab all the files listed there, but I wonder if somone hasn't already made a tool to do this.

Comment: When you add the projects to source control, the source control system should be able to figure what are the files that are part of the projects of the solution and add them. What VCS are you using?

Comment: SVN is not AFAIK aware of solutions. I guess I could use Subversion integration for visual studio. The code is already in SVN in the mess it's in at the moment though (I could perform and extract)